# Issues with flipping grid titles and what to do when it comes to touch devices

Tags: html, css, grid, touch

I have created a grid that flips and on each side will be a different picture, with a title. How can I overcome the issues I will face when it comes to viewing this on a touch device?

Also, I am having troubles getting the writing to not be in reverse when the square is flipped. If someone can help with that too that would be great.

Thanks for any help in advance!

```css
.grid{
  width:calc(95vw + 10px);
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  background-color:transparent;
  perspective:1000px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 10px;
    
}
.griditem{
  display:block;
  width:15vw;
  margin:5px;
  height:15vw;
  float:left;
}
.front{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/279315/pexels-photo-279315.jpeg') no-repeat;
  background-attachment:fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
  transform:rotateY(0deg);
  transition:.4s ease-in-out;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.back{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
  background:#fff url('http://www.dentoncorkermarshall.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Asia-Square-06.jpg?x92178') no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
  transition:.4s ease-in-out;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  z-index:2;
  font-family: montserrat;
}
.griditem:hover .front{
  transform:rotateY(180deg);
  transition:.4s ease-in-out;
}
.griditem:hover .back{
  transform:rotateY(0deg);
  transition:.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
      <div class="grid">
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back">olleh</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
        <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
       <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
      <div class="back"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might be better off using jQuery to handle this. You could accomplish your hover effect by using `.mouseenter()` and `.mouseleave()` to add a modifying CSS class that would affect`.front` and `.back`. Then you could use a `.click()` function for mobile devices so the user could tap each grid item to flip it.

Comment: Could you show me this within my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accomplishing this with jQuery. This will work the same on desktop, but should allow the user to tap/click to rotate images on mobile/tablet devices.

```js
if (matchMedia) { // media query event handler
  var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)"); // whatever your definition of mobile/tablet is
  mq.addListener(WidthChange);
  WidthChange(mq);
}

function WidthChange(mq) { // media query change

  var $gridItem = $('.griditem');

  if (mq.matches) { // if screen is bigger than 768px (iPad)
    $gridItem.mouseenter(function() { // user hovers on gridItem
      $(this).addClass('is-flipped'); // add mod class
    });
    $gridItem.mouseleave(function() { // user stops hovering
      $(this).removeClass('is-flipped'); // remove mod class
    });
  } else { // device bigger than iPad
    $gridItem.click(function() { // user clicks/taps gridItem
      $(this).toggleClass('is-flipped'); // toggle mod class
    });
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.grid {
  width: calc(95vw + 10px);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: transparent;
  perspective: 1000px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.grid h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 4.2em;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.griditem {
  display: block;
  width: 15vw;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 15vw;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.front,
.back {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.front {
  z-index: 1;
  background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/279315/pexels-photo-279315.jpeg') no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.back {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  /* Negative value to make it spin the right way */
  background: #fff url('http://www.dentoncorkermarshall.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Asia-Square-06.jpg?x92178') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 0;
  /* position behind .front */
  font-family: montserrat;
  text-align: center;
}

.griditem.is-flipped .front {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.griditem.is-flipped .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  z-index: 2;
  /* Position in front of .front */
}

.back span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid">
<h1>Title goes here</h1>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front">
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="griditem">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back">
      <span>Hello</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason that `.back` is showing up with flipped text is because you have it a a child of `.front` instead of as a child of `.griditem`. So when we flip `.front` around 180deg, then `.back` is getting flipped again.

Comment: Did you fix that flipped text problem? I copied your code into my doc and it's still reversed.

Comment: I hadn't included a solution for that the first time, just mentioned why it was happening. I've updated the code to fix the reversed text. Bascially, since you had `.back` as a child of `.front`, it was getting flipped around twice.

Comment: This works! Thank you. Is there a way I can get it centered?

Comment: Get what centered? The text?

Comment: Yes, sorry! The text

Comment: You want it centered horizontally and vertically?

Comment: Updated to center text in middle of box

Comment: thank you again for all your help. Would you happen to know if it's possible to get text on just the front image? I would like to add a title.

Comment: If you put the text in a `span` inside `.front` and apply the same styles I wrote for the `span` inside `.back`, it should work the same. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sort of, is there a way where it won't be stuck in each box, but rather will fill up multiple front boxes at once?

Comment: You could do that with absolute positioning, relative to `.grid`, yeah. Would you need the text to flip around with the tiles?

Comment: No, I would just need it to show on the front and that is it, once a box flips over it doesn't need to show.

Comment: That's what I'm asking. It's more complicated to hide the title while the tile is flipped, but is that what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I added an `h1` inside `.grid`, positioned absolute and used `z-index` to keep it behind the tiles when they're flipped.

Comment: How could i go about getting a different image on the back of each square?

Comment: Hm, you could give each one an `id` and assign a `background-image` for each one in your stylesheet. But it'd probably be easier just to put it inline on each `.back` element like `style="background-image: url('...');"`

Comment: I'm sorry but could you update my code to show that? I just want to make sure I do it correct.

Comment: Just put an inline `style` attribute on every `<div class="back">` and declare your background image there. So you'll have `<div class="back" style="background-image: url('/*image url here*/');"><span>Hello</span></div>`

Comment: What would I need to remove in the stylesheet so that it does not coincide with what i just added?

Comment: Inline styles would override what's in the stylesheet, so it's kind of up to you. I would leave the background size, position, etc. in the stylesheet, and only specify the image inline. You could leave the image in the stylesheet as a fallback if you want, too.

Comment: yeah no matter what image i place inline, it just goes right to what's in the css

Comment: nevermind got it! thanks again for your continuing help

Comment: The text is very big on mobile view, how can you change text size for different devices